# Why are my audio files (.wav) being corrupted when I copy them from a micro-SD card to my hard drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, sd-card

1. I have recently begun to use Ubuntu so have little experience with it. I am using Ubuntu Studio Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS. I installed it on an external hard drive connected by USB v.3 to my computer.
2. I have an audio recorder and when I copy files from the micro-SD card to my Ubuntu drive (external hard drive) they are corrupted. (This I do by inserting the micro-SD into the card reader slot of the computer.)
3. When I use Windows10 the same files are uncorrupted when copied to the computer internal drive. The Ubuntu system disk is not failing and works perfectly apart from the transfer of files from micro-SD. When I copy files from the computer internal disk to the Ubuntu disk the files are as they should be.
4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With large files being copied from any external device in Ubuntu, make sure you use the safely remove, or eject, or unmount feature. **Then wait till it says, it is safe to remove**. If you don't wait till it is safe, the copy will not be complete.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been doing that so I don't think that is the problem. I am wondering if it is something to do with buffers. When a file is read from the SD card it then must go to a buffer, I think, before it is read to the Ubuntu (USB) disk. That process is going wrong I think.

Comment: You're using an external USB drive for Ubuntu and then using a card reader slot on the computer. That's adding quite a bit of overhead/places where hardware could corrupt the files - which *could* be the problem. I'd play around with rsync, which should verify file integrity.

Comment: You are right in a way. Ubuntu (Linux in general) file systems store stores something to be written (the wav file in your case) in a RAM cache. This is more so when a large amount of writing is to be done (wav files are typically large). That's why waiting for safe to remove is important. You can use the [`sync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sync.8.html) command to force the computer to write everything stored in the cache.

Comment: Again, thanks to all who have answered. @kgiii When I looked at the audio in Spectrum view in Audacity [an audio editor] it looked like all the information was there but that, in the process of copying, it had been broken up into chunks and some of these were laid on top of others, and some silent spaces were left in between. I need to look up how to use rsync later, when I get the time. Maybe it will help.